# Apply the mean value theorem to find the largest possible value of $f(7)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

Suppose a function $f$ is continuous on $[-2,7]$, differentiable on $(-2,7)$, $f(-2) = 3$, $f'(x) \leq 2$ for all $x \in (-2,7)$. Apply MVT to find *largest* possible value of $f(7)$.

---

This is a different type of question ... usually I'm asked to prove that there exists a $c$ with the same slope, and then find that $c$. Here they don't even give me $f(7)$, but they do tell me that $f'(x) \leq 2$. How could this be of relevance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By MVT, we know that there is some $c \in (-2, 7)$ such that:
$$
f'(c) = \frac{f(7) - f(-2)}{7 - (-2)}
$$
Solving for $f(7)$, we have:
$$
f(7) = 9f'(c) + 3
$$
But since $f'(x) \leq 2$ for all $x \in (-2, 7)$, we know in particular that $f'(c) \leq 2$. So the largest possible value that $f(7)$ could ever take is at most:
$$
f(7) = 9f'(c) + 3 \leq 9(2) + 3 = 21
$$
Indeed, we can achieve this bound by greedily taking $f$ to be a straight line that passes through $(-2, 3)$ with a constant slope of $2$.